# Angular Table and filtering empty columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular) tutorial to build a sortable, searchable table using angular.

What I'm trying to do is only show columns that have at least one entry in it as the user is searching.  So basically, if the column is empty, do not show that column.

For example, in my code snippet, if the user searches for "XFish", I do not want the "Fish Type" column to appear;  If the user entries "YFish" I do not want the "Test Level" column to appear.  I'm just learning angular, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

```js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of sushi rolls
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2 },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 4 },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6 },
    { name: 'XFish', tastiness: 6 },
    { name: 'YFish', fish: 'Variety' }
  ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Sort and Filter</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body { padding-top:50px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <p>Sort Type: {{ sortType }}</p>
      <p>Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}</p>
      <p>Search Query: {{ searchFish }}</p>
    </div>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search da Fish" ng-model="searchFish">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              Sushi Roll
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'fish'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Fish Type
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'fish' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'fish' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'tastiness'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Taste Level
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'tastiness' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'tastiness' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
          <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
          <td>{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>

    <p class="text-center text-muted">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Read the Tutorial</a>
    </p>

    <p class="text-center">
      by <a href="http://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a>
    </p>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works. Key is here:

```
$scope.hasField = function(fieldName) {
  var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.sushi, $scope.searchFish);

  return filtered.some(function(roll){
    return typeof roll[fieldName] !== 'undefined';
  });
}
```

Note that `Array.prototype.some` is not available below IE9 but I thought that was acceptable.

```js
angular.module('sortApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.sortType     = 'name'; // set the default sort type
  $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
  $scope.searchFish   = '';     // set the default search/filter term

  // create the list of sushi rolls
  $scope.sushi = [
    { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2 },
    { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 4 },
    { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
    { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 6 },
    { name: 'XFish', tastiness: 6 },
    { name: 'YFish', fish: 'Variety' }
  ];


  $scope.hasField = function(fieldName) {
    var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.sushi, $scope.searchFish);
    
    return filtered.some(function(roll){
      return typeof roll[fieldName] !== 'undefined';
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Sort and Filter</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body { padding-top:50px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <p>Sort Type: {{ sortType }}</p>
      <p>Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}</p>
      <p>Search Query: {{ searchFish }}</p>
    </div>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search da Fish" ng-model="searchFish">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              Sushi Roll
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td ng-show="hasField('fish')">
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'fish'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Fish Type
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'fish' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'fish' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td ng-show="hasField('tastiness')">
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'tastiness'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Taste Level
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'tastiness' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
              <span ng-show="sortType == 'tastiness' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
          <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
          <td ng-show="hasField('fish')">{{ roll.fish }}</td>
          <td ng-show="hasField('tastiness')">{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>

    <p class="text-center text-muted">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Read the Tutorial</a>
    </p>

    <p class="text-center">
      by <a href="http://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a>
    </p>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```